# Index.html does not display the page when opened outside VScode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, web-development-server

I am very new to web development, so, if the questioned is very stupid, guide me appropriately and i will delete the page.

I am trying to create a map with `d3.js` and show the name on the region as tool-tip as the mouse moves over the map.

I have an `index.html`, `style.css` & an `main.js` file to build a webpage. I only use 1 `json` file which has geographical data of the region (it is actually a `topojson` file). All these files are in the same folder.

I use VScode for coding & the code works perfectly when I use `Live Server` within VS code.

However, when I open the `index.html` file directly from file explorer the `index.html` is blank.

I have another project where i have the same 3 files (code is different though) & that works when i open the file in file explorer.What am I doing wrong.Please guide.

My complete code is below (except for the 'karnataka.json' file). karnataka.json can be found in this github repository folder [here](https://github.com/covid19india/covid19india-react/tree/master/public/projected_maps)

```js
let margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10};
let width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
let height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let path = d3.geoPath()

let svg = d3.select("svg")
            .append("g")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

let tooltip = d3.select("div.tooltip");

let url = "karnataka.json"

// let obj = JSON.parse(url);
// console.log(obj.district)

d3.json(url, function(error, geoData) {
    if (error) throw error;  
    let geojson = topojson.feature(geoData, geoData.objects.districts);
    

  svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(geojson.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("stroke","rgba(9, 92, 151)")
            .attr("stroke-width",1)
            .attr("fill", "white")
            .attr("d", path )
            .attr("transform", "scale(1.5)")
            .on("mouseover",function(d){
                d3.select(this).attr("fill","rgba(36, 140, 183,0.3)").attr("stroke-width",1.2);
                return tooltip.style("hidden", false).html(d.properties.district);
            })
            .on("mousemove",function(d){
                tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
                       .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
                       .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
                       .html(d.properties.district);
            })
            .on("mouseout",function(){
                d3.select(this).attr("fill","white").attr("stroke-width",1);
                tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
            });
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

div.tooltip {
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <svg ></svg>
  <div class="tooltip"></div>  
</body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-queue.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascrip.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the browser developer console when you open index.html? Wonder if one of the scripts isn’t loading correctly or something. If you add a `<p>hello</p>` to index, does that show up? (if it does means index is loading but the JS files are not). Suspect console might have a message for you.

Comment: If I add `<p>hello</p>` it shows up but the map doesn't. Console does have hints! It seem that the scripts are not loading as you said. It may be because I am working behind a firewall. Thanks.

Comment: Yes the d3js scripts might not be loading if your firewall is blocking, thus the empty page. LMK if you get this figured out! Could also open your developer console, but then click the "Network" tab. Reload the same page with network tab open, you should see it spit out all the resources it grabs. You may see 404 for any files it can't access (probably D3 related scripts if firewall is blocking).

Comment: I will check. But here is the strange thing. When I open the `index.html` via live Server in VScode, then also I am behind the same firewall! It may be something else.

Answer (score 0):

**the vs code live server was work as a web server**

you run that code server-side any server like apache or Nginx etc so you need run on the server-side

if you running normal HTML code then mention the correct path for all the asset file like (.json and main.js )

> you writing the code in **react** so you have to make build first then
> it works

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue, was new to vs code. Code was working fine in live server but not outside**.

So what I found out was I forgot to link the file well. You can rectify by using double dot ../ before linking css, images , js, etc.

Comment: Could provide some example code illustrating your answer?